# Type guards with conditional types

Tags: typescript

I have following simplified code:

```
export type RT<T> = T extends Array<unknown> ? {v: T} : T;
function test<T extends Array<unknown>>(value: RT<T>): value is {v: T} {
    return "v" in value;
}
```

It gives me the error:

A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
Type '{ v: T; }' is not assignable to type 'RT'

Isn't the type { V: T; } assignable to type RT. Even though it is conditional, it must be assignable.

I must preserve the generic.

Maybe I should use different approach, the problem is I need to check and cast a "tree" type into "leaves" of different types.

Comment: If it's a "tree" vs. "leaf" situation, wouldn't it be a union type rather than a conditional type? `Tree<T> | T` or similar?

Comment: The T type is an object, array or primitive. The code traverses over the type recursively

Comment: What is your specific question here? Is it "make this work"? If so then you can use an intersection as shown [in this playground](//tsplay.dev/N92ajm), but I have no idea if that meets your needs. Or is it "why is this happening"? If so then the answer would involve pointing out various github issues like [ms/TS#56045](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56045). Or is it "should I use a different approach" in which case the answer would presumably be some alternate version that works, but that needs more use case details. Please [edit] to clarify the specific question so we can proceed.

Comment: The intersection works exactly how I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, like `RT<T>`, the compiler tends to *defer* evaluation of it until the generic type argument has been specified.  That means the compiler really has no idea what might or might not be assignable to `RT<T>` before it knows what `T` is.

This is still true even when `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type that fits entirely on the true branch or entirely on the false branch of the conditional type.  You might hope or expect that `T` being constrained to `Array<unknown>` would allow the compiler to evaluate `T extends Array<unknown> ? { v: T } : T` to `{ v: T }` even before `T` is specified, but this does not happen.

Yes, the generic constraint syntax `<T extends U>` is the same as the conditional type check syntax `T extends U ? X : Y`, but this unfortunately doesn't mean the compiler can use the former to evaluate the latter early.

There are various issues in GitHub about this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#31096](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31096) and [microsoft/TypeScript#56045](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56045). These are generally closed as design limitations.  For the foreseeable future, this is just how the language is.

---

So the compiler doesn't know that `{v: T}` will be assignable to `RT<T>` inside the call signature for `test()`, and thus it won't let you return `value is RT<T>`, since [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) must represent narrowings, not arbitrary type mutations.

If you want to proceed with a function like this, you'll need to rewrite the call signature.  Generally speaking if you know that type `U` is assignable to type `V` but the compiler doesn't, you can use the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `U & V` in place of `U`, since it knows that `U & V` is assignable to `V` no matter what `U` is.  And if you are correct about the assignability, then `U & V` will be more or less equivalent to `U`.  (You could also use `Extract<U, V>` with the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type). That means we can write

```
function test<T extends Array<unknown>>(value: RT<T>): value is RT<T> & { v: T } {
        return "v" in value;
}
```

and it will compile.  This should be enough for you to proceed.

---

Aside: presumably your actual use case motivates the type guard function.  But taken at face value it doesn't seem useful.  If we try to evaluate `RT<T>` more aggressively than the compiler does, and say that it must be `{v: T}` because `T` is constrained to `Array<unknown>`, then this results in:

```
function test<T extends Array<unknown>>(value: { v: T }): value is { v: T } {
        return "v" in value;
}
```

which means you will be calling `test(value)` as a way to check that `value` is of the type you already know it is.  That is, it's completely impossible for this function to return `false` and there's no obvious reason why you'd want or need to check this.  So while this example is sufficient for demonstrating how to alter a type predicate to be accepted, it doesn't seem to do so for any apparent purpose.  That's out of scope for the question as asked, though, so I won't digress any further.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKAVAPBgfHAXjgzlBmADsATAZzgEEooBDRLAVwoGsKIB3CvgD8cAN5wAbgC5icAL5wZGANwAoAGacAxjACWECgmA0YOUiHLU6jFm049+g3AAoJzADbtgMzDlwBKGTdPVF06Xzw4ADIxSSV5MVU4ZJTkqGAYdihDACIJHLhdQ2CvNTlVDW09AzgACwBberMySloGJlYObl4BXBcS71jpWTlAyQ8vQrpxYZIFUSTUlPTM7Lg8gqLxkLKgA)